# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 9): TypeError: Network request failed on React Native

Tags: android, react-native, asyncstorage

i try to use asyncstorage module to log in into my backend api service. this is the code:

```
const LoginScreen = (props) => { 
  
  const [username,setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password,setPassword] = useState('')
  
  
  const sendCred = async (props)=>{
    fetch("http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/user/login",{
      method:"POST",
      headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
     body:JSON.stringify({
       "username":username,
       "password":password
     })
    })
    .then(res=>res.json())
    .then(async (data)=>{
           try {
              if(data){
             await AsyncStorage.setItem('token',data.token)
             console.log('data: ' + data.token);
             props.navigation.replace("Home");
              }else{
                alert('Invalid username / password');
              }
              
           } catch (e) {
            alert('Cannot get TOKEN');
             console.log("error",e)
              Alert(e)
           }
    })
    
 }
```

it work on first try, but i do not know why now i cannot log in with this method with network rejection. can someone tell me whats wrong? thanks!

Comment: Please, try adding some more information. The specific network error that's being thrown would be useful. If you're testing on Android, check if it's an http error too

Comment: @FedericoOjeda ok i will edit the question